# Why does this happen after I train for 1 epoch？

Tags: pytorch, gpu

```
[E ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:719] [Rank 0] Watchdog caught coll
ective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(SeqNum=130725, OpType=ALLREDUCE, Timeout(ms)=1800000) ran for 1805536 milliseconds before timing out.                           
[E ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:406] Some NCCL operations have failed or timed out. Due to the asynchronous nature of CUDA kernels, subsequent GPU operations might run on 
corrupted/incomplete data. To avoid this inconsistency, we are taking the entire process down.                                                                     
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'                                                                                                
  what():  [Rank 0] Watchdog caught collective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(SeqNum=130725, OpType=ALLREDUCE, Timeout(ms)=1800000) ran for 1805536 milliseconds befor
e timing out.                                                                                                                                                      
WARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 63942 closing signal SIGTERM                                                                 
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: -6) local_rank: 0 (pid: 63940) of binary: /home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/bin/python    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main                                                             
    "__main__", mod_spec)                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code                                                                        
    exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 193, in <module>                                       
    main()                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 189, in main                                           
    launch(args)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 174, in launch                                         
    run(args)                                                                                                                                                      
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 718, in run                                               
    )(*cmd_args)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 131, in __call__                                 
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))                                                                                                
  File "/home/hustcsuser/miniconda3/envs/zcy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 247, in launch_agent                             
    failures=result.failures,                                                                                                                                      
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:                                                                                                 
======================================================                                                                                                             
./tools/train.py FAILED                                                                                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                             
Failures:                                                                                                                                                          
  <NO_OTHER_FAILURES>                                                                                                                                              
------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                             
Root Cause (first observed failure):                                                                                                                               
[0]:                                                                                                                                                               
  time      : 2022-04-14_03:43:04
  host      : cu01
  rank      : 0 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : -6 (pid: 63940)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 6 (SIGABRT) received by PID 63940
======================================================
```

Comment: Welcome to this community! Please refer to these guidelines [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regarding "why?", my first wild guess is that you might run out of memory on the GPU. Are you running on multiple GPUs? Try decreasing your batch size.